# Is this "smart" way of populating the admin page ok code-wise?

Tags: python, django

I am currently hooking a large database up to a django site and want to populate the admin page with a number of models. I am using inspect to get a list of classes from each model file (one file per database in MySQL) and then registering them by name.

```
from django.contrib import admin
import inspect
from .models import auth

# Auth
for pair in inspect.getmembers(auth):
    # returns a tuple with the class name and ref
    model = tuple[1]
    if tuple[0][0] is not "_" and tuple[0][0].upper() == tuple[0][0]:
        # it doesnt start with _ and does start with an uppercase
        admin.site.register(model)
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? Is getting class references like this bad practice? It just seems to easy to be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual "django" way of doing this  - is to use [`get_app_config()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_app_config) to get the `AppConfig` instance, then call [`.get_models()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_models):

```
from django.apps import apps

app = apps.get_app_config('auth')

for model in app.get_models(): 
    admin.site.register(model)
```